# find execution time of a program, given cycle count and GHz

Tags: mips, execution-time, cpu-cycles

I have to find the execution time (in microseconds) of a small block of MIPS code, given that:

```
it will take a total of 30 cycles
total of 10 MIPS instructions
2.0 GHz CPU
```

That's all the information I am given to solve this question with (I already added up the total number of cycles, given the assumptions I am supposed to make about how many cycles different kinds of instructions are supposed to take). I have been playing around with the formulas from the book trying to find the execution time, but I can't get an answer that seems right. Whats the process for solving a problem like this? Thanks.

Comment: You count the total instructions, multiply by the instruction execution time to get the total execution time. Without more information about your *specific* example, it's hard to determine why your answer doesn't match the given answer.

Answer (score 0):

My best guess at interpreting your problem is that on average each instruction takes 3 cycles to complete. Because you were given the total number of cycles I'm not sure that the instruction count even matters.

You have a 2Ghz machine so that is 2 * 10^9 cycles per second. This equates to each cycle taking 5 * 10^(-10) seconds. (twice as fast as a 1Ghz machine which is 1*10^(-9)).

We have 30 cycles to complete to run the program so...
30 * (5 * 10^(-10)) = 1.5 * 10^(-8) or 15 nano seconds to execute all 10 instructions in 30 cycles.